# Importing SVG as Grease Pencil Layer with Blender Python API

Tags: python, scripting, import, grease-pencil

From what I've gathered, if my objective is to import an SVG file as a Grease Pencil layer in Blender, one viable strategy seems to be importing the SVG as curves first, then making subsequent modifications to simulate the functionality available through the user interface:

```
bpy.ops.import_curve.svg(filepath='', filter_glob='*.svg')
```

Alternatively, I could potentially create an addon that activates this corresponding C code which is available in the Blender source on GitHub:

https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/main/source/blender/editors/io/io_gpencil_import.cc

I'm curious though, are these two methods the only pathways to replicate the UI-based import operation through scripting? I'm open to any insights or alternative suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.convert

convert to grease pencil
`bpy.ops.gpencil.convert(target='GPENCIL')`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.